# Polars pairwise sum of array column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars

I just got started with Polars (python) so this may be an ignorant question. I have a DF like the image shows where one of the columns (series) contains a numpy array of length 18. I would like to do a groupby on the `group` column and a pairwise sum aggregation on the series column, but I can't figure out a good way to do that in Polars. I can, of course, just do a map_elements and np.sum the arrays (like in the example) but I'm hoping there is a way to optimize it.

Here is my current implementation which achieves the desired effect but I don't think it is optimal because it uses map_elements. Is there a polars expression that achieve the same thing or is this the best I can do (without learning Rust, which I will someday)?

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
data = [
{'group': 1,
  'series': np.array([ 2398,  2590,  3000,  3731,  3986,  4603,  4146,  4325,  6068,
          6028,  7486,  7759,  8323,  8961,  9598, 10236, 10873, 11511])},
{'group': 1,
  'series': np.array([ 2398,  2590,  3000,  3731,  3986,  4603,  4146,  4325,  6068,
          6028,  7486,  7759,  8323,  8961,  9598, 10236, 10873, 11511])},
 {'group': 2,
  'series': np.array([1132, 1269, 1452, 1687, 1389, 1655, 1532, 1661, 1711, 1528, 1582,
         1638, 1603, 1600, 1597, 1594, 1591, 1588])},
 {'group': 3,
  'series': np.array([ 2802,  3065,  3811,  4823,  4571,  4817,  4668,  5110,  6920,
          7131, 10154, 11138, 11699, 12840, 13981, 15123, 16264, 17405])},
]
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
# this performs the desired aggregation (pairwise sum of 'series' arrays)
# sums first two rows together (group 1), leaves others unchanged
df.groupby('group').agg([
  pl.col('series').map_elements(lambda x: np.sum(x.to_list(), axis=0))
]).to_dicts()
'''
desired output

group    series
i64    object
2    [1132 1269 1452 1687 1389 1655 1532 1661 1711 1528 1582 1638 1603 1600
 1597 1594 1591 1588]
1    [ 4796  5180  6000  7462  7972  9206  8292  8650 12136 12056 14972 15518
 16646 17922 19196 20472 21746 23022]
3    [ 2802  3065  3811  4823  4571  4817  4668  5110  6920  7131 10154 11138
 11699 12840 13981 15123 16264 17405]

'''
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Does the result need to be a numpy series again?

Comment: No, but it should ideally be a list as it is going directly into a postgresql table as an array field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, any time you construct a polars DF and see that one of your columns is an `Object` then stop and go back and figure out how to make it a real dtype otherwise everything else you do will either not work or will rely on python iteration making it very slow.

Say you start with your `data` dict then you can do something like

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        {a:pl.Series(b) if isinstance(b,np.ndarray) else b 
         for a,b in x.items()} 
        for x in data
        ]
    )
```

After that, there's not really an obvious way to do it but one rule of thumb is that it's almost always easier to `explode` lists. In this case since the order of the list is important to the later aggregations you need to make an index column. Following that you explode by the `series` column and the index column. Then you `group_by` the `group` and index and sum the values. Since you want to end with lists you'd then `group_by` the group to put the values back into a list. All together, this is it:

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(series_idx=pl.int_ranges(0,pl.col('series').list.len()))
     .explode('series','series_idx')
     .group_by('group','series_idx', maintain_order=True)
     .agg(pl.col('series').sum())
     .group_by('group', maintain_order=True)
     .agg('series')
)
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬───────────────────────┐
│ group ┆ series                │
│ ---   ┆ ---                   │
│ i64   ┆ list[i64]             │
╞═══════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ [4796, 5180, … 23022] │
│ 2     ┆ [1132, 1269, … 1588]  │
│ 3     ┆ [2802, 3065, … 17405] │
└───────┴───────────────────────┘
```

#### Struct based method

If all of your lists are equal width you could do this:

```
cols_to_add=['series']
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col(col).list.to_struct(
            fields=lambda x, col=col:f"_{col}_{x}"
            )
        for col in cols_to_add
        )
    .unnest(cols_to_add)
    .group_by('group', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col(f'^_{col}_.+$').sum() for col in cols_to_add)
    .select('group', 
            *[pl.concat_list(pl.col(f'^_{col}_.+$')).alias(col) 
              for col in cols_to_add]
            )
)
```

This should also work for multiple `series` columns although I didn't test it with multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was afraid to use explode because I have a bunch of columns like 'series' but the way you did it seems manageable. I will try this and compare the performance with the np.sum() version. I'll post back the results but I just did a quick test and it appears "at least" as performant so I'll make this as answered.

Also, good note on the 'object' issue, I only just realized how to cast everything back from np.array to pl.series.

Thanks again.